# Why is my iPhone SDK 3.2 iPad code showing a white screen?

Tags: iphone, interface, ipad, sdk, builder

I'm trying to get a UISplitViewController working with an iPad app.

I have the table view controller linked up under the Master pane and a plain UIView under the Detail view.

I also have `[window addSubview:splitView.view];` in my code.

For some reason I just get a white screen even though the table view controller code is properly coded and linked under my nib.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Here's where you can find the code: http://drop.io/s28bu4t/asset/mydevice-hd-zip

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the right-side view controller of the split view is not set.
Both the left and right need to be set.
Try creating a view controller for the right side and change the class identity from UIViewController to your custom view controller.